# Expected time of sorting with external sort algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, external

Does anyone know what would be the minimal expected time(in seconds?) of sorting let's say 64MB binary file of 32 bit integers, that means sorting 16777216 values in ascending order, without using any internal sorting algorithms or data structures that could fire "Out of memory exceptions"? Just a data distribution in two auxiliary files and then merging them together to produce the final sorted sequence - this is how straight external merge sort works with *k* repetitions.

Some more assumptions about algorithm are that it is written in Java, it uses buffered readers and writers and it is running on dual core Windows machine with 5GB of memory, the rest is up to how the algorithm works in theory.

I know the question is a bit odd but some minimal time could be estimated I hope? If more info needed here, ask.

ThankS!

Comment: Why don't you just try it.

Comment: Why do you have to worry about OOM when sorting 64MB of data on a machine with 5G of RAM?

Comment: I am, but I need a reference value, that's why I am asking? To see how good or bad my time is?

Comment: The time taken only matters with respect to your specific requirements. Unless you can point to this specifically as a performance bottleneck, leave it alone and work on something that makes more impact; if it is a performance bottleneck, then no numerical value of expected time matters.

Comment: Andy, it could also be a 2GB file, on machine with 512MB of RAM? I just need what you guys think...

Comment: @henrich: Well, that's not what you said in your question. Questions shouldn't be moving targets.

Comment: I know what I said in my question :), those of you who know what I am talking about know, that the size of RAM is not important here.. Do you have an estimation maybe?? I am not mentioning bottlenecks, I just need an opinion if u have one of corse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a typical external sort, I/O time is usually your limiting factor. The *minimum* time it takes to do an external sort--if you use the standard algorithm--is the amount of time it takes to read and write the entire input file twice.

Consider that the external sort it done in two passes. In the first pass, the input file is read in blocks of some fixed size. As each block is read, it's sorted, and then written to a temporary file. At the end of the first pass, every item in the input file has been read once, and written once.

In the second pass, a k-way merge is used to combine the temporary files into a single sorted output file. Again, every item is again read once from disk, and written once to disk.

If the input file is already sorted, and the block sorting algorithm is well implemented, then the time to sort individual blocks is almost nothing. Same with the merge: an already sorted file is the best case for a k-way merge.

On modern desktop hardware, figure about 20 seconds per gigabyte for read, and perhaps double that for write. So you should expect absolute minimum time of about a minute per gigabyte. You could do some benchmarks yourself with reading and writing large files, but you have to either defeat the OS's file caching, or somehow take that into account. Otherwise you don't get good numbers.

The sorting and merging, of course, is going to take time. You can estimate how much time each block will take to sort by creating an array of whatever block size you have in mind, and then repeatedly filling it with random numbers and then sorting it. Time how long it takes to do 10 or 100 sorts, and take the average. That'll be a reasonable number for estimating.

In my experience, a good estimate of the time it takes to merge k blocks (i.e. the second pass) is pretty close to however long it takes to copy the input file times log(log(number of blocks)):

> merge time = (copy time) * (log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(number of blocks)))

Say I have a 1 GB file and I'm using 64 MB blocks. So there are 16 blocks to merge. I've already determined that it takes one minute to copy a gigabyte. So a good estimate of the time it will take to do the merge is one minute times log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(16)). `log(log(16))` is equal to 2, so it should take about twice as long to merge 16 input files as it would to just copy a single file of the combined size.

When you put it all together, you end up with the following for an estimate of the time required to do your typical external sort of a file size **S** using block size **B**

- Time to copy (read and write) a file of size **S**; plus
- Time to sort **S/B** blocks; plus
- Time to copy (read and write) a file of size **S**, times log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(**S/B**))

It's important, by the way, to do the block sort benchmark I mentioned above. Integers usually sort a lot faster than strings, for example, and strings that differ a lot in the first few characters will sort a lot faster than strings that are identical for the first 20 characters. When running your benchmarks it's always a good idea to use data that is as close to the real data as possible.

Comment: Oh, this is the answer I have been waiting for :) Thanks a lot! But there is one interesting thing that really surprises me....Linux (latest 64b Debian) handles this kind of problems a LOT better (read faster) than Windows 7 64b. The machines both use dual core CPU with nearly the same speed, but W7 uses SSD disk and Linux uses HDD and the difference in time is like 450 seconds when sorting 32MB file on Linux with HDD! Wouldn't expect such a difference? @Jim Mischel do you have any comments on that?

Comment: @henrich: I can't imagine it taking 450 seconds to sort 32 MB, much less a difference of 450 seconds. But in general, no, I can't say what the difference between the two might be, only that something seems wrong. There shouldn't be that difference with the same code running on similar machines.

Comment: It is muuuuch slower on all windows machines...W7 or W10, same code, same numbers....but big difference in execution time... And one more thing...W10 machine has Intel i7 CPU...the linux machine has dunno now, something AMD dual core, 8 years old tech.... wierd!

Comment: @henrich: If this is your code, you should be able to instrument it to determine what part is slow. Are you running the same program on both machines? Do all Java programs you run on Windows run slower than on the Linux system? Lots of variables to consider.

Comment: I am running the same code (just some file paths are different) on both machines. It is hard to answer if all programs run faster on Linux, cause this is the first "complex" solving program that I compared. The strange thing is also how program behaves with SSD and HDD drives, there are millions of reads/writes from/to HDD and it seems HDD performs better, because I have also tried to run it on the same machine but once with SDD and then with HDD and HDD was much better.
After all, Linux machine with an old HDD sorted the same data 4.8x faster then Windows machine with new SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using ObjectInputStream.  It would be much simpler and quicker and because `Integer` implements `Serializable`, it makes it that much easier. See:

```
long howLong(String path) throws IOException, ClassCastException{
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));

   List<Integer> allInts = new ArrayList<>();
   while(ois.ready()){
       allInts.add((Integer)ois.readObject());
   }
   ois.close();
   sortList(allInts);

   ObjectOuputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile(path)));

   for(Integer i:allInts){
       oos.writeObject(i);
   }
   oos.close();
   long end = System.currentTimeMillis();       

   //returns how long the alg took
   return (end-start)/1000;
}

private <E extends Comparable<E>> void sortList(List<E> l){
    boolean sorted;
    while(!sorted){
        soreted=true;
        for(int i=0,n=l.size()-1;i<n;i++){

            if(arr1[i].compareTo(arr1[i+1])>0){
                E tmp = l.get(i);
                l.get(i) = l.get(i+1);
                l.get(i+1) = tmp;

                sorted = false;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Try running this on your machine and see what it returns.  The output will be in **seconds**.

Comment: What you are trying to say here is, that ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutpuStream are faster than for example DataInputStream and DataOutputStream?

Comment: More so that they are faster than BufferedReader and BufferedWriter